# Spring how to add child entities when parent is created

Tags: spring, hibernate

So i have a showTime entity which has one to many relationship with Seating. So what i need to do is when a showTime is created i need to add x  seatings automatically to that showTime. I am not sure how to do it.

```
@Entity
public class ShowTime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="saloon_id")
    private Saloon saloon;

    private String date;

    private String time;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "showTime")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Seating> SeatingList;
    //getters setters

    Seating class

    @Entity
    public class Seating {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="showtime_id")
        private ShowTime showTime;

        private int seatNo;

        private boolean isTaken=false;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already mapped the seating list using `CascadeType.ALL`, that should make things easier.

Before you persist `ShowTime`, you should create the necessary seatings and make sure the relationship between then is set properly, then persist `ShowTime`.

Ex. persisting showTime and 1 seat:

```
ShowTime showTime = new ShowTime();
//code to setup other showTime attributes
Seating seat = new Seating();
showTime.getSeatingList().add(seat);
seat.setShowTime(showTime);
session.persist(showTime);
```

That should do it.